# Iterate properties of a data item in Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Suppose I have [a table like this](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlUk9vgjAU/yovvXARdbjLmC7ZsmQ77yocKjyVWIG0xWwhfPe9toBCNJnZCfr4/aO/t66ZksnstSynpwpZyJYaj6XgGl+iHGB58lOuua/5RiCEe+QpSrWKWPsWMQgzYpiRfUbM8ojZ6cDJV6LQFjaVmBKyBnOApgdbo2SPyWFTfBPhWKQoWknDIeBydkZ0FrNB1lueO4mY3+1qWf/y3YgK77Y1pD+5GsS5GhoNvtNRJTIrNSjUVQmC5zuy0K4fw89yjXLLE4RPWyXUzkZnWmAISsss37nRAX8uB40TSIpcaWj3IGxV1jGsYO1odaflvVMob+J0PAqNHjSTMegLU9IUheyRVPw14IdpZgS1bV0Dv9F9jrDmijtofPkvdoEv8nd1mcTEC+bBwn8I/ODJa20AKGIIWlbYT2ySELZcqPPQWA5wfdAbHov5yGOo15oMjG94xM9mNdwyUPWsmbDF9HE6Z+75xOJfNL5BpQ==):

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item.red="{ item }">
      <v-checkbox v-model="item.red"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.green="{ item }">
      <v-checkbox v-model="item.green"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.blue="{ item }">
      <v-checkbox v-model="item.blue"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

  interface Header {
    title: string
    key: string
  }

  const headers: Header[] = [
    { title: 'Date', key: 'date' },
    { title: 'Red color', key: 'red' },
    { title: 'Green color', key: 'green' },
    { title: 'Blue color', key: 'blue' },
  ]

  const items = [
    {
      date: '2023-12-29',
      red: true,
      green: false,
      blue: true,
    },
    {
      date: '2023-12-30',
      red: false,
      green: true,
      blue: true,
    },
  ];
</script>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I want to avoid defining each column template (red, gree, blue) manually. Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
    <template v-for="<propName in item where propName != 'date'>" v-slot:item.<propName>="{ item }">
      <v-checkbox v-model="item.<propName>"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

How to make this really work?

EDIT: [this](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) is what I ended up with:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
    <template
      v-for="header in headers.filter(h => h.key != 'date')"
      v-slot:[`item.${header.key}`]="{ item }"
    >
      <v-checkbox v-model="item[header.key]"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
    <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`item.${header.key}`]="{ item }">
      <v-checkbox v-model="item[header.key]"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

If that's what you are looking for, I can explain it in more detail if needed.

Comment: Yes, that's almost exactly what I need! Thanks a lot! I've updated the question a bit.